# Select rows which date (epoch) field equals a specific year

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I select rows from a table filtered by a specific year (e.g. `2019`) if date field is saved as epoch timestamp (millisecond, e.g. `1572093976705`) and just using SQL query

I don't want to get all rows in a list (use some programming language, e.g. Java), create `Date`/`Calendar` object from milliseconds and then check if items equal a specific year to filter the list

Comment: the duplicate link contains all th einfo you need: `strftime('%Y', 1572093976705 / 1000, 'unixepoch')`

Comment: The code in my comment converts 1572093976705 to year (2019), did you try it?. If this is not what you want edit your question and clarify.

Comment: @forpas so `"SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE strftime('%Y', dateMillisecondsField / 1000, 'unixepoch') = 2019` should work?

Comment: Exactly..................

Comment: @forpas ok, thank you. I'll go to test it

Comment: By specific year, do you mean the year as seen in UTC? Or the year as seen in a particular time zone?